# Getting this error while converting code to swift 3: clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I have converted my code from swift 2.2 to swift 3. It was working fine with swift 2.2, I am getting the following error.

clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

[Error picture: Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDiyD.png)

```html
Showing All Errors Only
CompileC /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MMDrawerBarButtonItem.o SwiftAndPHPSignUpExample/MMDrawerBarButtonItem.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.1.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Gadzoop-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Gadzoop-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Gadzoop-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Gadzoop-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -I/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/KaleemAhmad/Documents/FacebookSDK -F/Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/SwiftAndPHPSignUpExample/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -F/Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/SwiftAndPHPSignUpExample -iquote /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BSGridCollectionViewLayout/BSGridCollectionViewLayout.framework/Headers -iquote /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BSImagePicker/BSImagePicker.framework/Headers -iquote /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UIImageViewModeScaleAspect/UIImageViewModeScaleAspect.framework/Headers -isystem /Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -iquote -iquote /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BSImagePicker/BSImagePicker.framework/Headers -iquote /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UIImageViewModeScaleAspect/UIImageViewModeScaleAspect.framework/Headers -isystem /Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MMDrawerBarButtonItem.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MMDrawerBarButtonItem.dia -c /Users/KaleemAhmad/Desktop/gadzoop/SwiftAndPHPSignUpExample/MMDrawerBarButtonItem.m -o /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca/Build/Intermediates/Gadzoop.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gadzoop.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MMDrawerBarButtonItem.o

clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder Gadzoop-fdjqyafuystmzsbfrgmnuhrqohca at /Users/KaleemAhmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

and cleaning the project and then try again.

Comment: Have tried this but not working... issue remain the same.